# What makes a great writer's space?

Tags: habits, tools

If you have a usual or favorite place to write at home, what makes it so good?

I like having multiple places to write -- sometimes I find a change of scenery helps break a block -- but my most-used space is my desk at home.  Big, clicky ergonomic keyboard, a good spot for my tea, and the office adjoins my little one's playroom so I don't feel like I have to abandon him to write. :P

There's also plenty of room on the desk for my typewriter when the mood to go analog strikes.

Comment: Please note that this question has been retained for historical reasons, and shouldn't be considered a good example of an on-topic question for this site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, even without studying some dubious horoscopic sciences as feng shui, everybody at least feels that having your own work place for each kind of work you're doing is a significant efficiency boost. I think undisturbable place to write is not an option — it is a precondition. Once you have it, you can begin to write and at least be sure that you'll *finish* your work. But there are also some modifications that could help even more.

**1. Dual monitors.**

The most powerful boost for everybody who's writing or drawing something with help of the computer. I contrive a new usage for them every week or two for all fringes of my doings. Here are some examples that I just invented or used before:

- Drawing a fantasy map based on text or back to front;
- Looking to wikipedia while writing about tough subjects (i.e medical drugs);
- Modifying text from one screen on another;
- ...

**2. Cup of a drink.**

You've already knew it before :) But I'll add my pair of cents. I think people underestimate smells. There are not so many people working in a smell or taste art, but this *is* art. And changing taste of a drink lying in front of you will often reflect good on your creativity. So go and buy that new sort of black, green, red, white, {put your colour here} tea or learn how to make a mocha at last.

**3. Use the notebooks.**

Oh, what a disappointment that ideas only come to you when you've already gone to bed, and not in your writers space. Not anymore! Check [this great question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/405/how-do-you-track-random-thoughts-and-ideas) for details. And using of software notebooks is another option for the first point of this list.

**4. Adorn your space.**

The world is built the way that new ideas are coming from some set of previous. The more your place is yourselfish, the better. Some people are wild about junk collections and some can spend hours on looking into details of some large painting. Just don't let your place look vacuous for yourself.

**P.S.** As I remember, Stephen King wrote some good advices about writers space building in his book "[On Writing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743455967)".

Comment: Hmm, I only have a bottle of water on my desk. Maybe I should start drinking tea while writing. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @John Smithers Water is ok, really any drinkable liquid is favouring productivity. But hot drink with a tasty aroma, ahh, this is irreplaceable.

Comment: Eh, drinking means you have to stop and pee.

Comment: No drinking means you have to stop and die :(

Answer (score 4):

I like to keep away from my usual computer, as well as away from the games or other such distractions. Usually I also have a cup of coffee to drink and either music or a DVD to fill in as white noise. The upshot is that the whole mess is portable if I need to move. Lack of distractions is also key for me, or at least distractions I can filter out, so if my roommate is at home, headphones are a must.

The big thing though is that it's not the same computer as I use for everything else. Just the fact that I'm able to move away from my usual day to day computer usage helps me to focus on the task at hand instead of, not to put to fine a point on it, goofing off.

Answer (score 2):

I like my computer, a notepad, a pencil and something to fiddle with (usually my magnetic ball, a compass (which is now facing west because the magnet stuffed it up) or a toy car :D )

Basically paper for ideas, computer for writing, and something to do while im thinking (that isn't too distractive)

Answer (score 2):

No interruptions:

1. No phone
2. Door can be locked
3. Sign on door: ***Disturb at your own peril***.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to write in a notebook first and then type everything up (doing minor edits during typing).  I also prefer to be comfortable when writing and am not the type of person to fall asleep just because I'm reclining on a couch.

My favorite place to write is **my favorite comfortable couch**, either in the notebook or while typing on a laptop.

Some day I'd like to have a place with a big comfortable chair and an inspiration board of the type designers use to tack pictures on to, but that will have to wait until I have more living space.

Comment: And here I thought I was one of the last living souls to actually still use a pne/pencil and paper!

Answer (score 0):

I write while lying on my stomach my bed, with all the covers shoved to one side. I have Christmas lights hanging on the wall it's up against, which is really nice.

It's like when one of those expensively-done iPad commercials comes on and the girl in the commercial, who is rich enough to afford an iPad, is also apparently rich enough to have a patio with a bunch of string lights and a hammock. And, for some reason, she goes out there to use her iPad in the evenings and manages not to freeze to death. Well... okay. Whatever.

I prefer to be sitting at my desk for art, but I like to be lying down when I'm writing.